# Select class :first-of-type for same html child tag

Tags: html, css

I would like to select the first item, in this case a list item tag that has the class "red".
But :first-of-type takes into account the tag as a condition for first, even when the tag is not specified in CSS.

I would like the first occurrence in parent tags of a child with the .red class to be selected, even if it has the same tag as its siblings. Perhaps first-of-type is not the correct psuedo-class in this case?

CSS

```
.red:first-of-type {
    color: red;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
 <li class="red">Item (This is red)</li>
 <li class="red">Item</li>
 <li class="red">Item</li>
</ul>
<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li class="red">Item (I also want this to be red)</li>
 <li class="red">Item</li>
</ul>
```

[Link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/simbasounds/0vvk1q2n/)

Comment: You can't do that with `first of`... **There is no `first-of-class` selector**.

Comment: See the [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8539107/1811992) in the duplicate question

Comment: I was not aware of the general sibling combinator. Thank you.

Comment: Meta question: how should I explain that this question differs from the one it is marked as duplicating (which was more about parent tags)? I think this question specifically addresses the fact that first-of-type is not the same as the non-existent first-of-class, and has an answer for that exact scenario. So I'm just not sure how I would explain that in the question esp. seeing as I would have thought that the question as it stands was sufficiently specific and different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the first selector you paint all elements with `red` class in red color. With the second you override it by selecting every element with `red` class except the first.

```
ul li.red{ color: red; }
ul li.red ~ li.red{ color:black; }
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0vvk1q2n/4/)

Comment: That is quite a nice trick! I would never have though about it! I like this one also because your solution is compatible with oldies (IE7 for example).